# jquery checkbox - get the value of only the checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, checkbox

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(
    function() {

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        document.getElementById("chk_option").value += this.value + ",";
        alert($("#chk_option").val());
      } else {
        document.getElementById("chk_option_remove").value += this.value + ",";
      }


    }
  );
});
```

```html
<div>

  <center>
    <form id="form_tarif" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top:57px;" action="pricesinput" method="POST">

      <input type="hidden" id="chk_option" name="chk_option">

      <input type="hidden" id="chk_option_remove" name="chk_option_remove">

      <c:forEach items="${option_tarif_list}" var="option_tarif" varStatus="loop">
        <div class="checkbox1">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tarif_inclue[]" value="${option_tarif.id}" class="checkboxchk" id="option_tarif_chk_${option_tarif.id}">${option_tarif.libelle}
          </label>
        </div>
      </c:forEach
   </form>
 </center>

</div>
```

Hi,

Can you please help me with the following JS. I need to take the values of only the checked checkbox and use it in the id #chk_option. I will then use this id in my Java code for insertion into the database.

Here is part of my java code below:

```
String currentTypeTarifIdStr = request.getParameter("current_typetarif_id");
        Integer currentTypeTarifId = Integer.valueOf(currentTypeTarifIdStr);

        String TypeTarifIdToRemoveStr = request.getParameter("typetarif_id_to_remove");
        Integer TypeTarifIdToRemove = Integer.valueOf(TypeTarifIdToRemoveStr);

        Integer trimmedOptionSplit = 0;
        String optionChkStr = request.getParameter("chk_option");
        String[] optionSplitStrs = optionChkStr.split(",");


        String TypeTarifOptionToRemoveStr = request.getParameter("typetarif_option_to_remove");
        Integer TypeTarifOptionToRemove = Integer.valueOf(TypeTarifOptionToRemoveStr);





                        query = mEntityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM TarifTypeOptionEntity WHERE typeTarifId=:pId");
                        int deletedCount = query.setParameter("pId", currentTypeTarifId).executeUpdate();
                        mUserTransaction.commit();


                        for (String optionSplitStr : optionSplitStrs) {
                            String trimmedOptionSplitStr = optionSplitStr.trim();
                            // do something with trimmedOptionSplitStr
                            if (!trimmedOptionSplitStr.equals("")) {
                                trimmedOptionSplit = Integer.valueOf(trimmedOptionSplitStr);
                            }

                            mUserTransaction.begin();
                            TarifTypeOptionEntity typeTarifTypeOption = new TarifTypeOptionEntity();
                            typeTarifTypeOption.setTypeTarifId(currentTypeTarifId);
                            typeTarifTypeOption.setTarifOptionId(trimmedOptionSplit);
                            mEntityManager.persist(typeTarifTypeOption);
                        mUserTransaction.commit();
                        }

                    mUserTransaction.begin();
                    }
```

I will first delete everything in the database, then insert only the checked checkbox in the database. To do so, i should concatenate all the checked values  with a comma. Then in my java code, i will split it and remove the commas.

But it's not happening. can someone please help me with the coding and spot what i'm doing wrong.

EDITS:

No error in the console and the alert does work. Infact this code works perfectly. On clicking the checkbox the if clause is executed and each time i check another checkbox the value is added following a comma. This is those values that i will need in java. But it's not exacly what i need from this code.

Right now it adds only the value i unchecked from the checkbox into the database. But ofcourse this can't happen because this value is already present, 
.
so i get the error Caused by: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`locforall_booking`.`t_be_tarif_type_option`, CONSTRAINT`fk_t_be_type_tarif_option_t_be_tarif_option1`FOREIGN KEY (`be_tarif_option_id`) REFERENCES`t_be_tarif_option`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCA)`

Scenario of my problem:
If while i have 2 values checked and i don't uncheck it but check a third value, it will delete everything in the database and only keep that third value. But what i actually need is for it to delete everything in the database and keep all values including the third one.

Any Javascript expert around who can help please?

Comment: Did you try to debug whether your Java code is called at all? What does your browser's developer console say about the JavaScript? I don't see you make any server call...

Comment: I have updated my post answering your queries. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm no JavaScript expert but since you're using jQuery anyways why do you access the hidden field with standard dom manipulation methods (`document.getElementById("chk_option")`)? To test whether it is your JavaScript or not you could set a value manually (directly into the hidden field) and check if this value is passed to the servlet.

Comment: @thomas can you please show me an example of what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I guess you mean the second part, i.e. just add an initial value to the hidden field definition `value="somethingcompletelyirrelevantjusttocheckyouseethisinjava"`. Then don't hit any checkbox but submit the form as it is. If you get that value in your Java code the problem most likely is in your JavaScript code and you can rephrase your question accordingly and make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i have updated my post with the error received

Comment: Well at least that's a SQL or data error and I'd consider that to be out of scope for this question. Please be specific in your questions and don't just dump loads of code with lots of errors on us at once. The more effort you put into narrowing down your problems the more likely you'll get someone here to help you.

Comment: Hi again @thomas, i made a mistake earlier and added the value to another field. So, yes, i confirm seeing the value i added in JAVA. So my issue is definitely with the javascript code

Comment: So, do you set this alert: `alert($("#chk_option").val());`? Is the value correct? If not what does the browsers JavaScript console say? (in most browsers you get the developer options with JS console by pressing F12)

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: It's still hard to follow you as you seem to adress a number of issues: 1) you state you have problems with your JavaScript code (your edit sounds like you solved this), 2)  you have problems correctly transfering the values to the servlet, 3) you have problems with your database updates - that's a little much for one question. Most of those problems should be solvable if you debug your code step by step and check what happens there. You should then be able to spot where it starts to go wrong or at least narrow it down. Then solve the problems one after another.

Comment: Another comment on your JavaScript code: consider what would happen if the user continuously checks and unchecks the same checkbox, let's say with the value `1`. Your hidden fields' values would then look like this: `chk_option="1,1,1,1,"` and `chk_option_remove="1,1,1,"` (assuming the user checked 4 times and unchecks 3 times in between). So you'd either have to resolve that in your servlet or use a better structure in your JavaScript.

Comment: yes i noticed @thomas, i prefer solving it in the JS part. That's why i was hoping someone could help me improve my JS. Because i'm not that good in JAVA. But i will be happy if you can help on the JAVA part. You are the expert :)

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it why don't you just add a function as the `onsubmit` handler of the form and iterate over the checkboxes before actually submitting the form? That way you'd just collect the ids of the checked (and if you need it the unchecked) checkboxes once without having duolicate ids in each field.

Comment: Besides the above, please break down your question into several smaller pieces try to do some research and debugging on each of them and then ask as specific questions as you can. I'll consider this question closed as it's getting too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this using 2D array as:

```
<html>
```

```
    var items = [["abc.jpg", "xyz.jpg"],["123.jpg","345.jpg"]];
    alert(items[1][1]); // 345.jpg
</script>
</html>
```